# Can I properly change pip-2.7 command to pip?

Tags: macos, python, macports, pip

Basically trouble is that I have `pip-2.7` command in terminal but not `pip`. First thought was `sudo port select --list pip` will help, but it doesn't even has that group

```
Romans-iMac:~ holms$ sudo port select --list pip
Warning: Unable to get active selected version: The specified group 'pip' does not exist.
Error: The 'list' command failed: The specified group 'pip' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `alias`:

```
alias pip=pip-2.7
```

Comment: doesn't work with sudo!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `port select` for `pip` if you install

```
sudo port install py-pip
```

then

```
sudo port select pip pip27
```